# Switch statement c++

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I am writing a code to assign a scoring system to values of a card. I have a member function that takes an *int* and changes its value based on the scoring system. I can't seem to get it to output anything besides `10` :

```
int Obj::eval(int b)
{
    switch (b)
    {
    case 0:
        b = 11; //automatically assigns ace value of 11
    case 1:
        b = 2;
    case 2:
        b = 3;
    case 3:
        b = 4;
    case 4:
        b = 5;
    case 5:
        b = 6;
    case 6:
        b = 7;
    case 7:
        b = 8;
    case 8:
        b = 9;
    case 9:
        b = 10;
    case 10:
        b = 10;
    case 11:
        b = 10;
    case 12:
        b = 10;
    }

    return b;
}
```

Comment: Did you not notice what was happening when you stepped through with your debugger?

Comment: You've been missing the `break;` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Insert `break` at the end of each case. C's `switch` is "fall-through": if you don't prevent it, code just keeps executing next line: if `b` is `0`, *all* the assignments will get executed, in order. `break` will jump out of the `switch`.

I.e. your code needs to look like this:

```
switch (b)
    {
    case 0:
        b = 11; //automatically assigns ace value of 11
        break;
    case 1:
        b = 2;
        break;
/* ... */
```

Answer (score 1):

A switch case should end with a ***break;***. Otherwise there will be a fall through and all the subsequent cases will be executed.
Your code should look something similar to this.

```
switch(b)
{
   case 0:
     //bodyhere
     break;

   case 1:
      //bodyhere
      break;
}
```

It's important not to miss the break statements unless you intend to execute the following cases too.

Answer (score 1):

You should always use the break statement after each case because C++ will continue to execute the next case. For example:

```
switch(b)
{
    case 0:
        // body
        // body
        break;
    case 1:
        // body
        // body
        break;
    case 2:
        // body
        // body
        break;
}
```

You can also use a default as a last case. However, you don't need a break statement with the default.

```
switch(b)
{
    case 0:
        // body
        break;
    case 1:
        // body
        break;
    case 2:
        // body
        break;
    default:
        // body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch statements in C and C++ have a "feature" called [fallthrough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough), where if you don't actually `break` out of the cases, execution will just continue through to the next case (thus always resulting in `b` receiving `10`).

Add `break` statements after each case.

```
case 0:
    b = 11; //automatically assigns ace value of 11
    break;
case 1:
    b = 2;
    break;
case 2:
    b = 3;
    break;
// etc.
```

Comment: @StuartLC Probably :P

Answer (score 0):

Languages derived from C where control moves to the matching case, and then execution continues or "falls through" to the statements associated with the next case in the source text. Should use a `break` to avoid it.

```
case 0:
    b = 11; 
    break;
case 1:
    b = 2;
    break;
```

In your case `return` would be fine too,

```
case 0:
    b = 11; 
    return b;
case 1:
    b = 2;
    return b;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `case fallthrough` problem described above, there are more efficient means other than `switch` to map between values, such as [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

```
static map<int, int> myMap = { { 0, 11 }, { 1, 2 }, { 2, 3 }, ...  { 11, 10 }, { 12, 10 } };

int Obj::eval(int b)
{
    return myMap[b];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a break statement at the end of each branch. Otherwise the flow of control will continue to the next branch.